# How to get slide through indicators for GSAP Slider properly?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I found simple GSAP slider and edited it,

Now I have this in my [codepen](https://codepen.io/ChicagoJostik/pen/JjoeaGd).

And everything is working fine,
but if you click on indicator from first slide to last,
you will see that it tween through all slides,

because I'm using `tweenTo()` method on click event.

My question is how can I jump directly to slide that I clicked on indicator with my animation?

I can also use `seek()` method, but I will get my slider immediately without any animation.

Can you help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Aslan. If you want to have a direct transition from say, slide 1 to slide 4 (without showing slides 2 and 3) then you need to change your setup a bit. If you just want to speed past the ones in the middle, perhaps [this post](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/19393-fullscreen-sliders-horizontal-and-vertical/) can help. It saves the x location on each "slide" and animates to that x when necessary.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thanks a lot! Even here you give me advices)